# Java ArrayList - storing inputted integer into an array and printing it

Tags: java, arrays

Everything works except it's not giving me what I want. Where it says 'list.add(ln)', all it does is give me a boolean that says true.

Is there any way to store what I wrote from the keyboard into the array then print it out?

```
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ln = 1;     // prime the loop   

        while(ln != 0) { // begin while ln doesnt equal to zero

            System.out.println("\nFor list[" + n + "], enter a number.");
            ln = console.readInt();

            if (ln != 0){ // begin if the input from keyboard does not equal to zero

                System.out.println("Array " + list.add(ln));

                n++;    // update array size                    

            } // end if the input from keyboard does not equal to zero

            else

                System.out.println();

        } // end while ln doesnt equal to zero
```

Comment: What does `ArrayList#add(..)` do? Go through the javadoc.

Comment: Java has a documentation tool called `javadoc`. Use it when you don't know what JDK methods do.

Comment: u have Make list of Integar which is basically enter object of Integar. and u have to make for loop to retrieve this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are adding it on `System.out.println` which means that you are cheking a boolean that can be either true or false if you can enter it.

If you add it to the list and then print the index it would work:

```
if (ln != 0)
{ 
    list.add(ln);
    System.out.println("Array " list.get(n));
    n++;                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through array that you have created..It has already stored what you have entered..method just give acknowledge that it is successfully stored..

```
 for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
        {
        System.out.println("Array " +list.get(x)); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {

       Integer i=sc.nextInt();
       list.add(i);

     }while (i!=0);
```